# Test Maximum Entropy classifier

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

Is it possible to classify new data trough the Stanford Maximum Entropy classifier WITHOUT creating an external file including all the features?

In other words i have a test file in the following format:

**token1 \t feature1_1 \t ... \t feature1_N \t goldLabel1**

**...**

**tokenM \t featureM_1 \t ... \t featureM_N \t goldLabelM**

I was wondering if it is possible to use a data structure to include test data
without creating an external file.

Comment: Do you want to use the MaxentTagger or the ColumnDataClassifier ?

Comment: Are you saying you have the data in memory and you want to run on it in the Java API without having to write to a file ?

Comment: Exactly. I Want to create a data structure including the token at the first column followed by different columns (representing my features) and then the last column is the label assigned by the user (the goldAnswer). In this way i do not need to create a separate file and i can keep my data in RAM. The final system should be faster. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Also, i am using the ColumnDataClassifier to perform NER on my data. I used in the past the standard Stanford NER (the CRF based one) tool but it stopped iterating during the training stage and it was impossible for me to achieve a valid model. Then i tried the Maximum Entropy that provides me with good results but i still have this constraint about creating the separate file. As i am working with big PDFs (> 2gb), i would avoid to create a separate file for each PDF. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you review this method (line 409 in ColumnDataClassifier)

```
private Pair<GeneralDataset<String,String>, List<String[]>> readDataset(String filename, boolean inTestPhase) {
```

you can see how the code goes from a  file path to a `Pair<GeneralDataset<String,String>, List<String[]>>`

That is the key data object needed for evaluation.

If you review this method (line 2158 in ColumnDataClassifier) you can see how the evaluation is done

`public Pair<Double, Double> testClassifier(String testFile) {`

If you review the `main()` method (line 2011) you will see an example of the `ColumnDataClassifier` being built.

By looking at these three methods you can write additional code to do what you want to do and avoid writing to disk.